# How can I create a non-responsive web page for large screens only using Materialize CSS?

Tags: html, css, materialize, responsive

I am using Materialize CSS SASS version to build a website. I would like to make it non-responsive for large screens only (anything above medium/tablet view) but I would like to keep it responsive for medium and small. How can I do this?

An example of a website that kind of does this is the Tesla website:

https://www.tesla.com/en_GB/

It stops becoming responsive once a certain point has been reached

SCSS from the _variables.scss file

```
 // 12. Global
// ==========================================================================

// Media Query Ranges
$small-screen-up: 601px !default;
$medium-screen-up: 993px !default;
$large-screen-up: 1201px !default;
$small-screen: 600px !default;
$medium-screen: 992px !default;
$large-screen: 1200px !default;

$medium-and-up: "only screen and (min-width : #{$small-screen-up})" !default;
$large-and-up: "only screen and (min-width : #{$medium-screen-up})" !default;
$extra-large-and-up: "only screen and (min-width : #{$large-screen-up})" 
!default;
$small-and-down: "only screen and (max-width : #{$small-screen})" !default;
$medium-and-down: "only screen and (max-width : #{$medium-screen})" !default;
$medium-only: "only screen and (min-width : #{$small-screen-up}) and (max-
width : #{$medium-screen})" !default;
```

Comment: Just set it for the size you want, and don't care about the rest... Don't use Media Queries or things like. If it's responsive and you don't want it at all, remove all media queries from css or sass files

Comment: If you have the same content that will look different for different screen sizes then it is responsive.

Comment: @kevinniel thank you for your response. I would still like to keep it responsive for medium and small screens just not anything larger. I'm not sure what to remove or change in the _variables.scss file which I'm assuming is where the adjustment needs to be made. I will attach the file with the question.

Comment: `I would still like to keep it responsive for medium and small screens just not anything larger.` and your title : `How can I create a non-responsive web page for large screens only using Materialize CSS?`

Try to be logic and tell what you want at least.... that doesn't make sense....

Comment: Really? That seems pretty clear to me. 
I have a webpage which is responsive in large, medium and small screens. I would like to keep it responsive in medium and small but not for large screens. The Tesla website link I posted does something similar where it reaches a point and becomes non-responsive until medium screen size has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
//default mobile
body{
  color:red;
}
// Tablet Up
@media all and screen(min-width: 768px){
  body{
    color: green;
  }
}
```

Done!.

I hope you don't want to make the full framework stop being responsive.

**BUT**, if that is the case, redefine variables.

```
// Reasign media variables
$small-screen-up: 768px !default;
$medium-screen-up: 768px !default;
$large-screen-up: 768px !default;
$small-screen: 767px !default;
$medium-screen: 767px !default;
$large-screen: 767px !default;
```

With these changes, you should end up with a single responsive bracket.

Comment: Thank you for your response. No, I just want it to stop being responsive for large screens and up. I added with my question the SCSS from the file that contains the media queries. Any ideas on how to apply your solution to that SCSS? I am new to web developing so any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Lujane You can re-assign the media variables.